# Filtering with Azure CLI and JMESPath for network vnet peering list

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

I'm using the Azure CLI to get a list of vnet peerings: `az network vnet peering list`.  This returns json in the following structure:

```
[
  {
    ...
    "name": "prefix1-name",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "name": "prefix2-name",
    ...
  }
]
```

I am trying to filter the results by names starting with some prefix.  I have tried various combinations of the following:
`az network vnet peering list --resource-group my-rg --vnet-name my-vnet --query "[?starts_with(name,'prefix1-')].{name}"`
However this always fails with a message like `].{name} was unexpected at this time`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use `az network vnet peering list --resource-group my-rg --vnet-name my-vnet --query "[?starts_with(name,'prefix1-')].name"`. You do not need to include the `{}`in the `name`. This works on my side.

[image]

**Edit**

For the error message, I can reproduce it with these Azure CLI commands in PowerShell locally on the windows 10 machine. But this does not appear in my local [Linux Bash Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) as the above screenshots. This error also does not appear on PowerShell and Bash in the Azure cloud shell.

[image]

By my validation, It looks like a specific scenario on local PowerShell. When you filter with JMESPath, I just tried that the function `starts_with` or `contains` requires a space between the function, it works like these:

`--query "[?starts_with(name, 'vnet')].name"
 --query "[?starts_with (name,'vnet')].name"
 --query "[?starts_with(name,'vnet') ].name"
 --query "[?starts_with(name,'vnet')] .name"`

but this does not work as below.

`--query "[?starts_with(name,'vnet')].name"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately that was 1 of the variants I tried and I got the same result.  I just discovered the answer was putting a space between the ) and ]

Comment: For some reason I couldn't mark my answer as an answer for 48 hours, however your answer is much more complete so I've marked it as the answer.  Seems very strange - will raise this with Microsoft as a bug (assuming I can work out where to raise it!) as this can't be expected behaviour.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You may first try to raise this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues).

Answer (score 1):

The answer was apparently putting a space between the `)` and `]` so `az network vnet peering list --resource-group my-rg --vnet-name my-vnet --query "[?starts_with(name,'prefix1-') ].name` worked for me.  No idea why and not found any documentation that mentions anything like this.  If I remove that space I get the `].name was unexpected at this time` message.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows PowerShell issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#argument-parsing-issue-in-powershell. To workaround it, insert `--%` after `az` to force PowerShell to treat the remaining characters in the line as a literal.