# JMESPath starts_with function fails using Azure Cli

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli, jmespath

In [Microsoft Lab 09 > Exercise 4 > Task 1 > 2](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AZ400-DesigningandImplementingMicrosoftDevOpsSolutions/Instructions/Labs/AZ400_M04_L09_Controlling_Deployments_using_Release_Gates.html#task-1-remove-the-azure-lab-resources) it is instructed to list resource groups running the following command

```
az group list --query "[?starts_with(name,'az400m10l01-RG')].name" --output tsv
```

If I do run it, I get the following error

> ].name was unexpected at this time  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\..\python.exe" -IBm azure.cli group list --query
> [?starts_with(name,'az400m10l01-RG')].name --output tsv

I am not an expert in JMESPath, so, can you tell what is wrong with this expression?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your JMESPath expression, but it seems you are running the azure command from an odd local configuration of some sort, when the first step of that exercise instruct you to do this: _In the Azure portal, open the Bash shell session within the Cloud Shell pane._

Comment: Likewise. I just ran the same filter in cloud shell on my phone and it works fine so the JMESPath query is fine.

Comment: Thanks, yes I executed all commands, after adaptation to azure Cli, in inside Powershell on my box. So I am not sure if this command should be changed to adapt to azure cli, if yes, what should be changed? Thanks again

Comment: When I run the followin az group list --query "?starts_with(name,'az400m10l01-RG')" without the rest I get "echo Failed to load python executable"

Answer (score 4):

I have just came across this thread here
[Filtering with Azure CLI and JMESPath for network vnet peering list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154106/filtering-with-azure-cli-and-jmespath-for-network-vnet-peering-list?rq=1)
the issue got resolved by separating

```
)]
```

by a space

```
) ]
```

now the command runs fine in local powershell using azure cli

```
az group list --query "[?starts_with(name,'test') ].name" --output tsv
```

Comment: This is why they specifically advise you to use a **Bash shell** and not PowerShell.

Comment: Correct but as a professional and to automate operations I am obliged to use powershell  as having a unix machine is not an option