# azure cli query return invalid type for value received null

Tags: azure-cli, jmespath

Trying to query `az repos policy list` with query of:

- `[?type.displayName=='Build' && contains(settings.displayName, 'Test')]` returning message:

```
Invalid jmespath query supplied for `--query`: In function contains(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array', 'string'], received: "null"
```

Data is present while i query the fields, but when trying to query the value of them it is complaining.

tried with `--query "[?contains(settings.displayName, 'Test')]"` resulting in the same error.

Comment: I guess you do have some of those policies missing the settings object or missing the display name in the settings object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a link to bug [query will traceback while attempting to filter a nullable field](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9486) which contained instead a helpful explanation:

> The reason for to_string() is that some service principals have their homepage set to null which is not an array or string. So the jmespath library fails.
>
> This can be remedied by calling to_string on each object's homepage field so  that homepage is always a string for the purposes of contains()

so i updated my query: `az repos policy list --query "[?type.displayName=='Build' && contains(to_string(settings.displayName), 'Test') ]"`

which returned my exspected output.

Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant!  This worked like a charm for my query.  Was trying to access specific tags, but was getting None returned back for some of the values (possibly without tags or my specific tag).  Added your suggested 'to_string()' around it and it works like a charm

`az resource list --query "[?to_string(tags.automation).contains(@, 'this-is-my-tag')]`

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

You can specify the space between `)`& `]` in the last section as suggested in this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154106/filtering-with-azure-cli-and-jmespath-for-network-vnet-peering-list?rq=1) by @*rcarrington*

*For example:-*

```
--query "[?contains(settings.displayName, 'Test') ]"
```

*If the above does not work then please try to give a space between* `?` & `contains` .

*For more information please refer this* **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=examples%2Cbash) .